LLVM API produces invalid IR for ptr type
I am using LLVM 15 and I am trying to compile a language of my own (pretty much like Pascal in terms of syntax) to LLVM IR and I am using Ocaml.
When I try to create a struct and set its body to have ptr elements, then when I get a reference to that field of the struct and store to it, it has type str* which is invalid.
Here is a sample ocaml code that produces this:
let frame = named_struct_type llvm.context "frame1" in
struct_set_body frame ([| pointer_type2 llvm.ctx |]) false;
let frame_ptr = build_alloca frame ("frame_ptr") llvm.builder in
let base = build_struct_gep2 frame frame_ptr 0 "frame_elem_ptr" llvm.builder in
ignore (build_store v base llvm.builder);

where v is a function parameter called auxiliery and of type ptr.
The code above produces this IR:
  %frame = type { ptr }
  %frame_ptr = alloca %frame, align 8
  %frame_elem_ptr = getelementptr inbounds %frame, %frame* %frame_ptr, i32 0, i32 0
  store ptr %auxiliary, ptr* %frame_elem_ptr, align 8

When I try to compile this I get:
llc-15: error: llc-15: llvm_ir.ll:54:28: error: ptr* is invalid - use ptr instead

Which kiiind of makes sense to me...
I mean of course, I understand that the asterisk must be removed and if I manually remove it from the IR file it should compile (and it does actually!) but :

Why is this not allowed? (A pointer to a pointer is fine in C)
And most importantly, does anyone have any idea how could I fix it in my Ocaml code (or even C++ api instructions will be much appreciated!) ?

Generally, opaque pointers have caused me more trouble than good... :(

It turns out that LLVM 15 bindings in OCaml do not support opaque pointers at all! They are disabled automatically and there is no way to get away from this. So use LLVM 16 (or higher) if you want opaque pointers.

It's not allowed because it's a a pointer to an opaque pointer. You have to make up your mind, either your pointers are opaque ('ptr) or not (x*). Having a mixture makes about as much sense as a 32⅓-bit integer.
Fixing it is simple: Make up your mind which one you'd prefer and either use ptr or step back to an LLVM version with x*.

Ok thanks for that. Tough it's true that in other parts of my code I am using a mixture of opaque pointers and regular pointers (I will fix that now), it still doesn't make sense because in this particular part I have shared there is no use of regular pointers at all. Everything from start to finish is with opaque pointers. When the function is defined its paramater is defined explicitly to have opaque ptr type. Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Well, the transition to opaque pointers was a gradual one over the course of 2-3 years, so if your LLVM version is somewhere along the transition it'll have some sort of support for mixing. I can't muster much interest into the exact state during one particular stage of the transition. If your code is to survive for a while you'll have to upgrade to pure opaque pointers at some point anyway, won't you?
